# Play DRM protected content inside ADOBE AIR

Tags: air, jwplayer, flowplayer, drm

I'm new to adobe air, and was trying to integrate this (http://flowplayer.electroteque.org/securedrm) plugin to adobe air application. But the video dosen't seems to be playing, using HTMLLoader inside AactionScript3. However, I m able to play any not drm related content using same code.

This is what I'hv done.

My action script contains this.

```
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost:8888/index.html");

    var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600);
    var options:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
    options.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.STANDARD;
    options.type = NativeWindowType.NORMAL;
    options.transparent = false;
    options.resizable = true;
    options.maximizable = false;

    var htmlload:HTMLLoader = HTMLLoader.createRootWindow(true, options, true, bounds);
    htmlload.stage.nativeWindow.notifyUser(NotificationType.INFORMATIONAL);
    //htmlload.stage.nativeWindow.addEventListener(Event.CLOSING, onHTMLPageClose);
   //htmlload.addEventListener(HTMLUncaughtScriptExceptionEvent.UNCAUGHT_SCRIPT_EXCEPTION, scriptError);

    htmlload.stage.nativeWindow.x = stage.nativeWindow.x;
    htmlload.stage.nativeWindow.y = stage.nativeWindow.y;
    htmlload.stage.nativeWindow.activate();

    try {
    htmlload.load(request);
    }
    catch (e:Error) {
    trace("navigate failed");
    }
```

And this is how my index.html looks like;

```
<html>

<script src="http://static.electroteque.org/js/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drmIdentPlayer">
</div>

<script>
    jwplayer("drmIdentPlayer").setup({
    flashplayer: "http://static.electroteque.org/swf/jwplayer.flash.swf",
    width: 660,
    height: 350,
    primary: "flash",
    playlist: [
    {
    file: "mp4:BigBuckBunnyAuth.mp4",
    provider: "http://static.electroteque.org/swf/drmrtmp-provider.swf",
    streamer: "rtmp://rtmp.electroteque.org/cfx/st",
    }
    ],
    plugins: {
    "http://static.electroteque.org/swf/securedrm-2.0.swf": {
    displayNotifications: true,
    checkVersion: true
    }
    }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Have tried using flowplayer as well, but same result, here is my HTML;

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/js/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://flowplayer.electroteque.org/js/flowplayer.securedrm-3.6.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<a id="drmplayer" style="display:block;width:660px;height:350px;"></a>

<script>
    flowplayer("drmplayer",{src:"http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf",version: [10, 2]}, {
        plugins: {

            drm: { url: "http://static.electroteque.org/swf/flowplayer.securedrm-3.2.7.swf" },

            // the "tube" skin
            controls: { url: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.controls-tube-3.2.15.swf"}
        },
        clip: {
            url: "BigBuckBunnyAuth.f4v",
            accelerated: false,
            autoPlay: false,
            baseUrl: "http://videos.electroteque.org"
        },
        log: {
            level: 'debug',
            filter: 'org.flowplayer.rtmp.*, org.flowplayer.securedrm.*,org.flowplayer.controller.*'
        }

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Basically I m able to play above on my local tomcat (on FireFox/Chrome). But the same is not getting played on Adobe AIR, and I believe AIR uses the same WebKit rendering engine used by the Safari web browser. Also, if i use non-drm protected content, it plays.